# Is there a short cut in R to merge two time series variables based on a common date observation?

Tags: r

I have a a time series data set with variables S&P 500 stock indice core CRB. Although most days match some don't much since in one of the variables the observations are not available. Therefore, the observations differ. For example;

| Date | S&P 500 | Date | CRB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27.05.2022 | 7 | 27.05.2022 | 0.89 |
| 26.05.2022 | 1 | 26.05.2022 | 0.54 |
| 24.05.2022 | 2 | 25.05.2022 | 0.73 |
| 23.05.2022 | 5 | 24.05.2022 | 0.75 |
| 21.05.2022 | 7 | 23.05.2022 | 0.63 |
| 20.05.2022 | 9 | 21.05.2022 | 0.64 |

So my question is, is there a way in R, where the days match and the dates that don't have values for the other variable will be implemented to have a result for example;

| Date | S&P 500 | Date | CRB |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 27.05.2022 | 7 | 27.05.2022 | 0.89 |
| 26.05.2022 | 1 | 26.05.2022 | 0.54 |
| 24.05.2022 | 2 | 24.05.2022 | 0.75 |
| 23.05.2022 | 5 | 23.05.2022 | 0.63 |
| 21.05.2022 | 7 | 21.05.2022 | 0.64 |

Ofcourse I will lose observations but that is not a problem.

Would mean a lot if someone knows a code on how to do that. thank you!

Comment: So what happened? Can you elaborate

Answer (score 1):

To exclude all values in the second date column and get your desired output, you can use `setdiff()`:

Data:

```
df <- read.table(text = "Date1  SP500   Date2   CRB
27.05.2022  7   27.05.2022  0.89
26.05.2022  1   26.05.2022  0.54
24.05.2022  2   25.05.2022  0.73
23.05.2022  5   24.05.2022  0.75
21.05.2022  7   23.05.2022  0.63
20.05.2022  9   21.05.2022  0.64", header = TRUE)
```

```
df[!(df$Date1 %in% setdiff(df$Date1, df$Date2)),]
```

output:

```
# Date1 SP500      Date2  CRB
# 1 27.05.2022     7 27.05.2022 0.89
# 2 26.05.2022     1 26.05.2022 0.54
# 3 24.05.2022     2 25.05.2022 0.73
# 4 23.05.2022     5 24.05.2022 0.75
# 5 21.05.2022     7 23.05.2022 0.63
```

Here, `setdiff(df$Date1, df$Date2)` finds all values that are in `Date1` but not `Date2`. Then we index the rows in `df` (i.e., `df[,]` by finding the rows that contain only dates in `Date1`

Comment: yes, I have tried this as well but it doesn't match the date. There are still different dates in the same rows. I want for example 25.05.2022 on both but since one doesn't have that then, it should delete that row and keep the values with the same date.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a clearer, more detailed explanation of the data you have, the data you want, and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

To do this while maintaining the order, make use of `dplyr::inner_join`

```
inner_join(df[1:2], df[3:4], 'Date') %>%
   mutate(Date1 = Date, .before = 'CRB')

         Date   S&P 500        Date1      CRB
1  27.05.2022    7        27.05.2022    0.89  
2  26.05.2022    1        26.05.2022    0.54  
3  24.05.2022    2        24.05.2022    0.75  
4  23.05.2022    5        23.05.2022    0.63  
5  21.05.2022    7        21.05.2022    0.64
```

Comment: It gives me an error that says: Error in `check_join_vars()`:
! Join columns must be present in data.
x Problem with `Datum...3`.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.